# SpringBoot environment is null in docker

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have a springboot java application with gradle and some environment variables in application.yml :

```
spring:
  profiles: development
server:
  port: 3100
database:
  connectionString: mongodb://localhost:27017

---

spring:
  profiles: production
server:
  port: 80
database:
  connectionString: prodCS
```

My dockerfile :

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-Dspring.profiles.active=development","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

I am trying to run the docker locally but my environment returns null properties

```
@Configuration
public class MongoUtilities {
  @Resource
  public Environment env;
  private static String mongoUri;

  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  }

  @Bean
  public boolean ReadConnectionString() {
    mongoUri = env.getProperty("database.connectionString");
    System.out.println("Loaded connection Uri : " + mongoUri);
    return true;
  }
}
```

I've had trouble before with the environment variable being null but managed to fix it. It now runs perfectly in intellij with flag `--spring.profiles.active=development`

I am building using `gradlew build docker` and starting docker using `docker run springio/my-app`

It's all pretty standard, I'm just a beginner to this area.

Any ideas?

Comment: try changing your docker run command to `docker run -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=development" springio/my-app`

Comment: Tried it and it achieved the same goal as -Dspring.profiles.active=development so nothing changed. My environment has value but my problem is that each time I write env.getProperty() I get null value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've manager to fix it by adding my application.yml to the docker in build.gradle:

```
docker {
  dependsOn build
  name "${project.group}/${bootJar.baseName}"
  files bootJar.archivePath, 'application.yml'
  buildArgs(['JAR_FILE': "${bootJar.archiveName}"])
}
```

Then I had to copy application.yml to the image using the dockerfile

```
COPY application.yml application.yml
```

Then I set spring's configuration to my application.yml

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-Dspring.config.location=application.yml", "-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of doing it namely

- Passing Spring Profile in Dockerfile

  ```
  ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-Dspring.profiles.active=dev","-jar","/rest-api.jar"]
  ```
- Passing Spring Profile in Docker run command

  ```
   docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev" --name rest-api dockerImage:latest
  ```
- Passing Spring Profile in DockerCompose

  ```
   rest-api:
   image: rest-api:0.0.1
   ports:
     - "8080:8080" 
   environment:
     - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev"
  ```

I have written in [detail over here](http://www.littlebigextra.com/use-spring-profiles-docker-containers/), how you can achieve the above 3 approaches.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I can already set the active profile. The problem is that all profiles didn't have any properties in them

Comment: Sorry, I missed your point in question. Is your application.yaml in src/main/resources folder only? Even for some reason if the profile propertiers are not getting picked up, what about the default properties  are they getting picked up ?

Comment: Abhi The application.yml was in my root directory but the problem is that the docker didn't deploy it. I managed to fix it and I wrote an answer for others